# Cannot publish my class library to WIndows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to publish on my Windows Server 2008 R2 my MVC 4 project!

The problem is that my solution apart from the mvc projecty has also a class library project (in this class library prokject also has a web reference to web service).

So what I have done so far - as always I have right click Publish of my mvc project and I choose File method and I give the address. I decided to make the same thing with my class library project and I gave the same physical address to be uploaded as my mvc project so they can be in the same folder.

But unfortunately when I start the site I see:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the full stack trace of the error. Perhaps look on the windows server event log.

Comment: If your web project depends on the library you do not have to publish the class library seperately. As it is a dependency it will automatically be deployed with your web application.